# Activity indicator (spinner) while JSON is loading

Tags: ios, json

How to show spinner while loading data with JSON and putting in to labels?

Using this code to call JSON and putting values in labels:

```
-(void)loadJSON {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/service/?id=John&response=json"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSDictionary *loan = [json objectForKey:@"person"];

    labelFirstName.text=[loan objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    labelLastName.text = [loan objectForKey:@"lastName"];
    labelNickName.text = [loan objectForKey:@"nickName"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Your Json Loading with MBProgressHUD.

Study this - https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD